# In codepen, Intersection observer has different behavior from browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

If I write [this codes](https://codepen.io/heyran/pen/LYpgqmO) in separate HTML, CSS and Javascript files and open it with a browser, sticky sharebar appears when the target observed in middle of viewport height, but in codepen appears when the target observed in bottom of viewport height. What is the reason?

```
{
    class StickyShareBar {
        constructor(element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.contentTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('js-sticky-sharebar-target');
            this.showClass = 'sticky-sharebar--on-target';
            this.threshold = '50%'; 
            this.initShareBar();
        }

        initShareBar() {
            if(this.contentTarget.length < 1) {
              this.element.addClass( this.showClass);
              return;
            }
            if(intersectionObserverSupported) {
              this.initObserver(); 
            } else {
              this.element.addClass(this.showClass);
            }
        }

        initObserver() {
            const self = this;
            var observer = new IntersectionObserver(
              function(entries, observer) { 
                self.element.classList.toggle( self.showClass, entries[0].isIntersecting);
              }, 
              {
               rootMargin: "0px 0px -"+this.threshold+" 0px"}
            );
            observer.observe(this.contentTarget[0]);
        }
    }

    const stickyShareBar = document.getElementsByClassName('js-sticky-sharebar'),
      intersectionObserverSupported = ('IntersectionObserver' in window && 'IntersectionObserverEntry' in window && 'intersectionRatio' in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype);

    new StickyShareBar(stickyShareBar[0]); 
}
```

Comment: Your problem is solved. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a problem with `rootMargin` and the fact that you are using an `iframe`

https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#dom-intersectionobserver-rootmargin

https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues/372

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the **targeted** element. When the srcollbar can reach the targeted element ( `js-sticky-sharebar-target` ) then the event is fired. When the content container width is smaller the scroll wheel can't reach the targeted element. For this reason it's not showing on browser or small screens. I have changed the targeted element and placed it on the top. Now it's working as you expected.

**Changed HTML:**

```
<div class="container new-js-sticky-sharebar-target">
```

**Changed JS:**

```
this.contentTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('new-js-sticky-sharebar-target');
```

***See [Demo](https://codepen.io/motahar_hossain/pen/jObjKLr?editors=1010)***

Comment: I don't want to change the target element. I want to sharebar appears when the target reachs to center of viewport height.

Answer (score 1):

The IntersectionObserver spec has been expanded to allow passing a `Document` as an argument to `root`. So if you pass the `Document` of the iframe as the argument for `root` it triggers a special case where it will consider the iframe's window as the viewport and hence it will work as expected. In something like codepen you probably have no control over this but outside of that it will fix your problem.

See https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues/372

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same issue many times when using Intersection Observer in CodePen. Like others have said, it's because CodePen renders your work in an iframe and the rootMargin doesn't work the way you might expect because of that.

I have tried pretty much every solution that has been described in other threads and **this is the only one I have gotten to work:** https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/MWbqOaJ

The solution is to wrap your HTML in a full width and height element that you set to `position: fixed` and `overflow: auto`. Then set that element as the `root` for your observer. `rootMargin` will now work as expected in your pen.